# GWT + Maven + Tomcat + JNDI + Eclipse configuration

Tags: maven, gwt, jndi, eclipse-luna, tomcat5.5

I've got a project using GWT 2.6.1 + Maven 3.2 + Tomcat 5.5 (yes, I know it's an old one ...) + Eclipse Luna which is using JNDI allowing for external parameters to be configured.

As you might know, the context XML file is located at */conf/Catalina/localhost/myWebApp.xml* where *myWebApp* is the Java web application name.

I am using **gwt-maven-plugin** for this project (the one from mojo haus) which has the version 2.6.1.

Here is my current configuration :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <goal>i18n</goal>
                            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
                <configuration>
                    <module>xxx.yyy.myModuleName</module>
                    <runTarget>myWebPage.html</runTarget>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>xxx.yyy.zzz.client.ui.i18n.OlbClientMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <extraParam>true</extraParam>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Dgwt.compiler.optimizationLevel=9</extraJvmArgs>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xms128M</extraJvmArgs>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1200M</extraJvmArgs>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-XX:MaxPermSize=768M</extraJvmArgs>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

As you can see, i am using the noServer (configured to "true") option because I must use an external Tomcat container for the server side.

My question is : 
How can I enable client side AND server side debugging within my actual configuration through a step-by-step help.

I've made a lot of attempts but i can't make things working.

I've tested running the "mvn gwt-debug" which tries to connect to default port 8000 and then connecting a remote java application which connects to my webapp to localhost:8000 and it works well, but it's only for the server side.

I also need to debug the client side in the DEVMODE.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to run a remote server. First is using using DevMode with -noserver and pointing the war directory to the output war directory of the external server. The second way is to use the CodeServer entrypoint and run a WTP server runtime and set the launcher directory to tomcat output war directory.

I prefer the second routine, and built automation into the GPE fork. 
http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/servers/Tomcat.html - see it in action here. There are videos and such.